# The difference between "identically distributed" and having "common probability space"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have two random variables X and Y. 
If we say they have a common probability space, does it mean that they are identically distributed? What is the difference between "identically distributed" and having "common probability space"?

Would you please give me an example of two random variables having the same probability space and but are not identically distributed, and another example of two random variables identically distributed and but they do not have the same probability space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you asked for two specific sorts of examples, here are some small ones.  First, consider a sample space consisting of two elements $a$ and $b$, with the probability measure that gives both points probability $\frac12$.  Consider the following two random variables $X$ and $Y$, both defined on this sample space. $X(a)=X(b)=Y(a)=0$ and $Y(b)=5$.  Then the probability distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are very different, so they are not identically distributed.

Second, consider a probability space consisting of four elements, $a,b,c,d$, each with probability $\frac14$. Let $Z$ be the random variable on this space defined by $Z(a)=Z(b)=0$ and $Z(c)=Z(d)=5$.  Then this $Z$ and the $Y$ from the previous paragraph are identically distributed, but they are defined on different sample spaces.

(If you want *really* small examples, both sorts of examples can be built using $1$-element sample spaces, but then there's not much probability or randomness visible.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, these are really good examples! Now I understand that the important issue is how the random variables are defined. So if the random variables are defined the same then  “identically distributed” and having “common probability space” would be equal?

Comment: @May I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment. If two random variables on the same probability space are "defined the same", they'd be the *same* random variable, not just identically distributed. On the other hand, I don't see what "defined the same" would mean if they were on different probability spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The same sample space says nothing about identically distributed.

I get the feeling you do not know what a sample space, if so, you need to look this up.

only when they live on the same sample space, it is makes sense to talk about dependence/independence but this has nothing to do with distributions being the same or different.

Example: Let $(\Omega_1,F,P)$ be a probability space with a random variable $X$ and $(\Omega_2,G,Q)$  be a probability space with random variable $Y$. $X$ and $Y$ can have the same distribution

Let $(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2,F\times G,P\times Q)$ be the product probability space of the previous two spaces, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution and live on the same sample space.

but you could have made $X$ and $Y$ to have different distribution, the same would occur.

**conclusion: same/different sample space says nothing about distribution**

Comment: The question does not mention dependence/independence but talks only about the distributions of the random variables.

Comment: @gabe i know. I have answered the question. I said this to highlight why sample space is important from practical point of view.

Comment: when we say common probability space, does it mean that for example they are normal random variables but their means and variances are different?

Comment: @May No -- those would be different probability spaces.

Comment: @gabe but if they have the same means and variances, they would be identically distribute, right? so in this way, “identically distributed” and having “common probability space” are the same. would please you give me a simple example?

Comment: @gabe you can build infinitely many random variable on the same sample space, so what you said is that not correct

Comment: @May no same mean and variance does not say anything about what sample space it is on!

Comment: @May for a simple example, see my answer.

Comment: @Lost1 would you please give me a simple example which shows their differences?

Comment: @Lost1 -- yes you can build (infinitely) many random variables on the same sample space.

Comment: @Lost1 for the first part of the example "X and Y can have the same distribution" if they have the same distribution, doesnt it mean that they have the same probability space and probability distribution function and as a matter of fact the same probability space?

Comment: @May no, it does not. all this sample space is just often no more than an arbitary construction. You can build a normal distribution using $\mathbb{R}$ as sample space but you can also build one on the interval $[0,1]$ using different probability measures. I do not think why you are even concerned if you are not studying probability theory. This is really basic measure theory, you have not learnt any measure theory, then this is borderlining impossible to explain.

Comment: @May A random variable is a measurable function from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}$. using different sample spaces, you need a different function. If you take a coin toss, your can take {H,T} as your sample space, the random variable $f$ is $f(H)=H, f(T)=T$, with $P(H)=P(T)=1/2$ but at the same time you could have taken {1,0} as your sample space, the random variable $f$ can be $g(1)=H$, $g(0)=T$ with $Q(1)=Q(0)=1/2$. $f$ and $h$ are random variable with same distribution on different probability spaces.

Comment: @Lost1 thanks now I understand

Comment: So if the random variables are defined the same then “identically distributed” and having “common probability space” would be equal?

Comment: @May no, construct $\{H,T\}^2$, then first and second coin toss has the same distribution but they are not the same random variable?

Answer (score 0):

A probability space includes more information than a sample space. Whereas a sample space is all of the possible outcomes, it does not include the probability of each of the outcomes.

Consider a biased coin vs an unbiased coin. These have different associated probability spaces but the same sample spaces. They have the same possible outcomes (heads or tails) but different probabilities associated -- hence different distributions.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space

Comment: are you not aware that you can have 2 identical copies of the same sample space?

Comment: you build an identical random variable on each of them, they have the same distribution?

Comment: then you take the product space and product $\sigma$-algebra and product measure, suddenly they are on the same space and still independent?

Comment: @gabe your example shows 2 random variables with different probability spaces but the same sample space, right?

Comment: @May that is correct.

Comment: @gabe I know that different sample spaces does not mean different probabaility spaces. My question is If they have the same probability space, are they identically distributed and vice versa.

Comment: @May Oh sorry, I may have misread your question initially as re: probability distributions and sample spaces.